# How to generate method or constructor parameter names against provided arguments in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Suppose I have the following class and respective instance:

```
case class Account(name: String, age: Int, amount: BigDecimal, currency: String)

Account("name", 93, 100, "USD")
```

**Question**: Is there a shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA that will generate parameter names against passed arguments, i.e.

```
Account(name = "name", age = 93, amount = 100, currency = "USD")
```

This is very useful when you have a constructor or a method taking a long list of parameters and helps to read / refactor some old code.

Please note that I am aware of `Ctrl+P` showing parameter info and I am also aware of `Inlay Hints` setting in IntelliJ showing the hints in the editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `alt`+`Enter` and then choose "use named argument ...":
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There exists [intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html) `Use named arguments`

[image]

which transforms

```
User("Worf")
```

to

```
User(name = "Worf")
```